# Where can I find the saved credentials for my PHP for Google App

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have written A PHP project to update the Google Spreadsheet, while currently, I as using the code

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS)
));
```

but I cannot find where the credentials are stored thus when I change account, I met a problem is that "caller does not have the permission", I think it is still using the old credentials.
Could someone tell me where I could find it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [PHP Quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/php), `saved credentials` are saved in `$credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);`

```
// Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
$credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
  $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
} else {
  // Request authorization from the user.
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
  print 'Enter verification code: ';
  $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

  // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
  $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

  // Store the credentials to disk.
  if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
    mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
  }
  file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
  printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
}
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```

You may check this documentation for more information: [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app)